# Javascript Condition syntax

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get a condition working but not sure about the syntax...

How would I write this in jquery/javascript?

```
if (value.type) == 'football' then {
 //do something
} else {
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (value.type == 'football') {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Reference: [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), [== vs ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use).

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((value.type) == 'football') {
 //do something
} 
else {
  //do something else
}

or

if (condition) {
 //do something
} 
else if(condition) {
  //do something else
}
else {
  //do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS

```
if (value.type === 'football')
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

or you could use the short if

```
message = ('value.type' === 'football') ? "type is equal to football" : "type is not equal to football";
```

jQuery is just a js library and it doesn't have if else implementation cause it really not needed.

Hope it helps